# Can't execute symlink pointing to nfs file - permission denied

Tags: linux

I'm running Arch Linux:

```
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~] uname -a
Linux nathanb-box 3.9.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 3 22:45:16 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a symlink (which is actually a symlink to a symlink):

```
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~/bin] readlink spt
/usr/software/test/bin/spt.current
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~/bin] readlink `readlink spt`
spt.1.11
```

These should be valid:

```
[nathanb@nathanb-box /usr/software/test/bin] l spt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bob engr   11 Sep 25  2011 spt -> spt.current
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bob engr 208K Feb 14  2012 spt.1.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bob engr 193K May 29 09:45 spt.2.19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bob engr    8 Mar  8  2012 spt.current -> spt.1.11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bob engr    8 Jun  6 10:01 spt.last -> spt.2.19
```

Note that /usr/software is nfs-mounted, not local.

Now, observe the problem:

```
[nathanb@nathanb-box ~/bin] ./spt
bash: ./spt: Permission denied
[nathanb@nathanb-box /usr/software/test/bin] ./spt.current
bash: ./spt.current: Permission denied
[nathanb@nathanb-box /usr/software/test/bin] ./spt.1.11
spt.1.11> quit
[nathanb@nathanb-box /usr/software/test/bin]
```

Although I can execute the binary itself, I can't execute any symlinks pointing to the binary.

This appears to be a security feature in either Arch Linux or in the kernel I'm running, since our ancient RHEL systems can execute these symlinks just fine. I thought it might be like [this question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/284573/permission-denied-for-symlink-to-executable-in-nfs-mounted-directory-with-the-st), but my /proc filesystem doesn't have that particular knob to turn.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post might have the answer you're looking for:

[Permission denied for symlink to executable in nfs mounted directory with the sticky bit enabled](https://serverfault.com/questions/284573/permission-denied-for-symlink-to-executable-in-nfs-mounted-directory-with-the-st)

Comment: Had you read the entirety of my question, you would have noted that I linked the post you mention. It's possible that I missed the answer to that question in that thread, so if you could point it out to me I would greatly appreciate it.